# Add ribbon (tab) to contact form outlook addin

Tags: c#, .net, vsto, outlook-addin

I am trying to add a ribbon/tab in outlook contact in C#. I added a ribbon and in its xml i have written following code.

```
<tab idMso="TabAddIns" label="mySoftwareTab">
    <group id="ContentGroup" label="Appointments">
      <button id="GetAppointment" label="Get Appointments" screentip="Appointment" imageMso="ViewAppointmentInCalendar" onAction="GetAppointmentPressed" size="large"
              supertip="Get all appointments."/>
    </group>
  </tab>
```

This creates tab in every screen including main area (as image shows mySoftwareTab at location A & B)

[image]
But if I change idMso to TabContact it creates only a button on contact (C location in image).

I want tab to be created at outlook contact page only (At location B in image).
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a getVisible callback method, and gate the method based on the inspector window you want it to appear.

```
<tab idMso="TabAddIns" label="mySoftwareTab"
     getVisible="myTab_GetVisible">
```

Then, create the callback delegate method called mySoftwareTab_GetVisible

**UPDATE**: *Final solution provided by original poster (Kash) so credit goes to him. ... re-posting this for anybody else viewing the question and answer.*

```
    public bool myTab_GetVisible(Office.IRibbonControl control) 
    { 
        if (control.Context is Outlook.Inspector) 
        { 
            Outlook.Inspector oInsp = control.Context as Outlook.Inspector; 
            if (oInsp.CurrentItem is Outlook.ContactItem) 
            { 
                return true; 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                return false; 
            } 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            return false; 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: `if (control.Context is Outlook.ContactItem)` this condition is never true.

Comment: After bit alteration following is the working code.

`public bool myTab_GetVisible(Office.IRibbonControl control)
        {
            if (control.Context is Outlook.Inspector)
            {
                Outlook.Inspector oInsp = control.Context as Outlook.Inspector;
                if (oInsp.CurrentItem is Outlook.ContactItem)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }`